Generalization to Rauch's comparison theorem
I was trying to do an exercise of proving that a geodesic of length greater than $\pi$, in a manifold of sectional curvature greater or equal to $1$, has a conjugate point of multiplicity at least $n-1$, where $n$ is the dimension of the manifold and by "multiplicity" I mean the Morse index of the geodesic.
I was attempting to solve this using Rauch's comparison theorem but it only implies that the geodesic has a conjugate point since its length is bigger than $\pi$. This leads me to the following problem: Is there a version of Rauch's comparison theorem where instead of the geodesic not having conjugate points we require only the Jacobi field along the geodesic to not zero along the interval? If the result was still true under these hypotheses I could use this result to prove that the multiplicity of the conjugate point of the curve in my exercise is at least $n-1$ since we have $n-1$ Jacobi fields to compare with on the sphere of curvature $1$.
Alternatively, I would also appreciate any counter-example in case this generalization of Rauch's theorem is not true.
Here is a link to the usual Rauch's comparison theorem for reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rauch_comparison_theorem
Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks
